# Size of DOM element when in it's "auto"

Tags: jquery, css, size

How i can get the `width` or `height` of DOM element when in CSS it's size is `auto`? When i try use

```
$("#element_id").width();
$("#element_id").height();
```

it returns *zero*. So i need the real size of the element.

Comment: `jQuery.width()` and `jQuery.height()` *should* return computed width and height values; if they don't, it's likely that the element (or one of its descendants) is hidden. In order to correctly calculate element dimensions, the element needs to be visible (not `display: none`).

Answer (score 0):

As stated above the .width() and . height() should be computed values.

You will have problems if the items are displayed none or if they are not taking up the width you would expect them to. this could be due to the elements not being floated or similar.

A good way to see what the width or height of an element should be is to use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) in firefox.

once you select an element click on either the Computed or the layout  tabs on the right in there you will see the values for the selected element, when you hover the element in the tree view it will also should you what space the element is taking up on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I put a source code at this link http://jsfiddle.net/F42Rx/.

You can see that I put the `div` with an `auto` width and made an `alert` that shows that it returns the computed width.

Regards

Comment: My element at init is display : none

Comment: Thenk. Posted link is very useful for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I solves the problem. As already said the item was set `display: none`. So I set the CSS property to `hidden: hidden`. And everything works fine.